# Left Join Complex with first row of other select

Tags: sql, db2, iseries-navigator

I have a complex SQL query for DB2 Database on Iseries.
I Simplify my scenario for any help.

Update 23 October 2013 10:54PM:

Ok I Explane explain my problem...Imagine that you have a TABLE named "Products" that 
contains all the movements for customer code with the amount... For Example:

```
**Product** table


CUSTOMER_CODE | PRODUCT_CODE | DATE_MOVEMENT | QTA_MOVEMENT | AMOUNT
______________________________________________________________________
 C0001        | BOOK         | 20133101      | 400          | 60
 C0001        | BOOK         | 20131231      | 40           | 30
 C0001        | BOOK         | 20130701      | 1            | 6
 C0001        | BOOK         | 20130310      | 4            | 15
 C0002        | BOOK2        | 20131210      | 4            | 15
 C0002        | BOOK2        | 20131110      | 4            | 18
 C0002        | BOOK2        | 20131230      | 42           | 130
 C0002        | BOOK2        | 20130610      | 42           | 140
```

I need to create a SQL QUERY that give me a SUM for any PRODUCT_CODE of ANY CUSTOMER of QTA_MOVEMENT and AMOUNT COLUMN....and... 
and simultaneously print the LAST QTA_MOVEMENT, LAST AMOUNT, LAST DATE MOVEMENT of any ROW (customer_code + product_code + years).
The result query is this:

```
**Product** table

C_CODE | PRODUCT_CODE | YEAR | T_QTA | T_AMOUNT | L_DATE  | L_QTA_MOV | L_AMOUNT|
_________________________________________________________________________________
C0001  | BOOK         | 2013 | 445   | 111      |20131231 | 40        | 30
C0002  | BOOK2        | 2013 | 92    | 303      |20131230 | 42        | 130
```

I have simplified my problem with this example...

Have you some suggest for the SQL Query that I need?

Comment: In your example, each customer only has one product, each product only has one customer.  Presumably you want a result row for each customer, product combination.

Comment: You can have more products for customer...

Comment: er, what's the first row's `DATE_MOVIMENT` (is 'movement' actually misspelled?) supposed to be?  The format of that entry doesn't match the rest of the rows.  And please tell me that's an actual date type...  Also, please correct the `T_AMOUNT` entry for book-2, as it doesn't match the expected value...

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your query is screwed up. It is difficult to find out what your actual goal is only by looking at your query.

First, I would avoid creating temporary tables as much as possible. Why can't you put a table directly in the from statement instead of having a `(select ... from ... where) as table_alias`? I am not 100% sure, but I expect that the query optimizer is not able to optimize these statements.

In your query, you join TOT with LASTM. However, you need TOT to create the 1 line in LASTM. Why not join earlier with LASTM? It would help when you explain what you are trying to do so someone can help you rewriting the query.

On a last note. I see that you are joining the same table (TABLEORIG) with itself. Which leaves the suspicion that the table design is not very helpful. Don't know if you have the option to change the table design.

Comment: Peter: tnx for your Help....I have update my question...so that I hope now is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how useful it is to see the last transaction of prior years.  But since editing your question, it seems you are asking for something like this:

```
  with hst as
  ( select customer_code                     as customer
         , product_code                      as product
         , cast(year(date_sold) as num(4,0)) as yr
         , date_sold
         , quantity_sold                     as qty
         , sales_amount                      as amt
         , int(row_number() over
                (partition by customer_code, product_code, year(date_sold)
                 order by date_sold desc
              ) )                            as recent
      from sales_history
  ), tot as
  ( select customer, product, yr
         , sum(qty)   as t_qty
         , sum(amt)   as t_amt
     from hst
     group by customer, product, yr
  )
  select t.*
       , h.date_sold  as l_date
       , h.qty        as l_qty
       , h.amt        as l_amt
    from tot t
    join hst h    on  h.customer = t.customer
                  and h.product  = t.product
                  and h.yr       = t.yr
                  and h.recent   = 1
    order by customer, product, yr;
```

The `row_number()` function will assign a sequence number based on the descending sales date, within each partition group.  The latest in the group will be sequence 1.  This allows us to join the summary information to the latest detail row.